# Windows CreateProcess and output redirection

Tags: c, windows, io-redirection, createprocess

I'm working in a C project, windows environment using WinAPI.
My function execs a command `(e.g. : "dir C:\Users")` it received as a param, and returns its output.
It is ran from a DLL so it must not spawn a `cmd.exe` windows, which means I can't use `_popen`. So I use `CreateProcessA`, and a pipe to catch stdout.

**Here is the code :**

```
char *runExec(char *command, int *contentLen) {
    char *ret=NULL,*tmp=NULL;
    DWORD readBytes;
    int size=0;
    char buffer[128],cmdBuf[4096];
    HANDLE StdOutHandles[2];

    CreatePipe(&StdOutHandles[0], &StdOutHandles[1], NULL, 4096);

    STARTUPINFOA si;   
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    si.hStdOutput = StdOutHandles[1];
    si.hStdError = StdOutHandles[1];
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    snprintf(cmdBuf,4096,"cmd /C %s", command);
    if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, cmdBuf, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW | DETACHED_PROCESS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
        printf("Error createProcess : %d\n",GetLastError());
        return NULL;
    }


    CloseHandle(StdOutHandles[1]);
    printf("Before read\n");
    while (ReadFile(StdOutHandles[0], buffer, 127, &readBytes, NULL)){
        printf("IN WHILE\n");
        buffer[readBytes] = 0;
        printf("read %d bytes\n", readBytes);
        size += readBytes;
        tmp = (char *)realloc(ret, size + 1);
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            free(ret);
            return NULL;
        }
        ret = tmp;
        strncpy(ret + (size - readBytes), buffer, readBytes);
        ret[size] = 0;
    }
    printf("Readfile returned with %d, read %d\n", GetLastError(),readBytes);

    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    CloseHandle(StdOutHandles[0]);
    printf("#%s#\n", ret);

    return ret;
}
```

**And the output is :**

```
Before read
Readfile returned with 109, read 0
#(null)#
```

**So from that I understand that :**
 - My loop isn't even executed once
 - ReadFile reads nothing and returns Broken Pipe immediately

I have read various stackoverflow and MSDN pages, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: From STARTUPINFO documentation: *If this flag is specified when calling one of the process creation functions, the handles must be inheritable and the function's bInheritHandles parameter must be set to TRUE. For more information, see Handle Inheritance.* Both requirements are not fulfilled by your code.

Comment: Aaaaand I can't read... Thanks for that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, handles must be inheritable, which means replacing the `CreatePipe` like this :

```
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pipeAttrib;
memset(&pipeAttrib, 0, sizeof(pipeAttrib));

pipeAttrib.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
pipeAttrib.bInheritHandle = NULL;
pipeAttrib.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

if (!CreatePipe(&StdOutHandles[0], &StdOutHandles[1],&pipeAttrib, 4096)) {
    printf("Create pipe error %d\n", GetLastError());
    return NULL;
}
```

And setting `CreateProcess` 5th parameter (`bInheritHandles`) to `TRUE` instead of `FALSE`.